# Как по значениям из колонки создать другие колонки с бинарными признаками?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, машинное-обучение, обработка-данных

```
a = pd.DataFrame([{'id': 1, 'b': 'a', 'd_1': 0},
                  {'id': 1, 'b': 'c', 'd_1': 0},
                  {'id': 1, 'b': 'c', 'd_1': 1},
                  {'id': 1, 'b': 'a', 'd_1': 0},
                  {'id': 1, 'b': 'g', 'd_1': 0},
                  {'id': 1, 'b': 'c', 'd_1': 0},
                  {'id': 1, 'b': 'a', 'd_1': 0}])
```

Нужно взять значения из колонки 'b' и по ним создать новые столбцы:

```
        pd.DataFrame([{'id': 1, 'b': 'a', 'd_1': 0, 'a': 1, 'c': 0, 'g': 0},
                      {'id': 1, 'b': 'c', 'd_1': 0, 'a': 0, 'c': 1, 'g': 0},
                      {'id': 1, 'b': 'c', 'd_1': 1, 'a': 0, 'c': 1, 'g': 0},
                      {'id': 1, 'b': 'a', 'd_1': 0, 'a': 1, 'c': 0, 'g': 0},
                      {'id': 1, 'b': 'g', 'd_1': 0, 'a': 0, 'c': 0, 'g': 1},
                      {'id': 1, 'b': 'c', 'd_1': 0, 'a': 0, 'c': 1, 'g': 0},
                      {'id': 1, 'b': 'a', 'd_1': 0, 'a': 1, 'c': 0, 'g': 0}])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Вариант 1**: воспользуйтесь [pd.get_dummies()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html):

```
res = a.join(pd.get_dummies(a["b"]))
```

**Вариант 2**:

```
res = pd.get_dummies(a, prefix="", prefix_sep="", columns=["b"])
```

**Вариант 3**: [sklearn.preprocessing.LabelBinarizer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelBinarizer.html#sklearn.preprocessing.LabelBinarizer)

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelBinarizer

lb = LabelBinarizer()

res = a.join(pd.DataFrame(lb.fit_transform(a["b"]), 
                          columns=lb.classes_, 
                          index=a.index))
```

результат:

```
In [169]: res
Out[169]:
   id  b  d_1  a  c  g
0   1  a    0  1  0  0
1   1  c    0  0  1  0
2   1  c    1  0  1  0
3   1  a    0  1  0  0
4   1  g    0  0  0  1
5   1  c    0  0  1  0
6   1  a    0  1  0  0
```